# How to pass javascript variable from Rails view to action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, action, rails-admin

I have a list of user emails in a bit of Javascript code in my view that I have created for my action. The view is in haml format.
I want to press a submit button on a form and access this list of emails in the same action or another action.

I've tried using form_tag, form_for and just normal html forms, however I keep running into different issues. I've also tested with link_to and button_to tags.

Here's what we have for the Action:

```
module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Actions
      class BulkProperties < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base
        RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)

        register_instance_option :collection do
          true
        end

        register_instance_option :http_methods do
          [:get, :put]
        end

        register_instance_option :controller do
          proc do
            @all_users = User.all
            @all_properties = UserProperty.all
            @all_roles = Role.all
            binding.pry
            if request.get? # EDIT
              respond_to do |format|
                format.html { render @action.template_name }
                format.js   { render @action.template_name, layout: false }
              end

            elsif request.put? # UPDATE
              binding.pry #Just testing this
          end
        end

        register_instance_option :link_icon do
          'icon-lock'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And this the part of my view giving me issues:

```
%form
  .multiselect-form
    .wrapper{"data-children-count" => "1"}
      %select.collection{:multiple => "multiple", :id => "multi"}
  %hr/
  %h1 List of user properties
  -@all_properties.each do |prop|
    %input{:name => prop.name+"checkbox", :type => "checkbox", :id => prop.name+"checkbox"}
    #{prop.name}
    %input{:name => prop.name, :type => "text", :id => prop.name}
    %br
  %input{:name => "submit", :type => "submit", :formaction => 'http://localhost:3000/admin/user/bulk_properties?Application=8&Company=1&locale=en', :method => 'put'}
%br/
%br/
```

The outcome is that I am led to a CanCan issue where I'm getting 'You are not authorized...'. This is because the url actually ends up holding the parameters and so it tries to redirect me to a webpage that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented an action that uploads a file with js to S3 and sets the value of a form field with javascript then i use that url on the rails admin action.

I'm pasting it all because in the past that would have helped me in these cases by comparing my approach to a working approach.

Here are the relevant (simplified)files:

```
# app/views/rails_admin/main/update_orders_and_line_items.html.haml

= form_tag(method: :post) do
  = hidden_field_tag 'uploaded-file-url', '', id: 'uploaded-file-url'
  = submit_tag 'Submit', class: 'action-button-pink'
```

```
# app/assets/javascripts/google_cloud_storage_field.js 

let url = get_url(fileInput);
let valueField   = $('#uploaded-file-url');
valueField.val(url);
```

```rb
# lib/rails_admin/config/actions/update_orders_and_line_items.rb

module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Actions
      class UpdateOrdersAndLineItems < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base
        # Might cause random bugs if enabled
        register_instance_option :pjax? do
          false
        end

        register_instance_option :http_methods do
          [:post, :get]
        end

        register_instance_option :controller do
          proc do
            if request.post?
              url = params['uploaded-file-url']

              do_stuff_with(url)
            elsif request.get?
              # [...]
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I believe the source of your bug is using the `%form` tag, the default method of a form is GET and thats why your browser tries to redirect you to some page, if you use like i did `form_tag(method: :post)` and make sure the emails are on the hidden_field_tag value, you'll get your list on the action.rb

Comment: Thank you for this, It's put me on the right track and I now have my params in my action!